# Ensuring NodeJS spawn stdout.on activates on newlines only

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am running an external program through NodeJS using the spawn functionality, like this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var java = spawn('java', ['-jar', 'misc.jar']);
  java.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data.toString());
      io.emit('chat message', data.toString())
  });

});
```

And the expected stdout should like this (with the newlines in place):

```
>java -jar misc.jar
0000
0
0001
1
...
```

But when I run it through NodeJS/Socket.io I get:

```
listening on *:3000
000
0
0

000
1
1
...
```

I would like to make sure that the call to `java.stdout.on('data', function(data){...` **only happens when data is a newline character or the subprocess is exited**.

It seems like there is another some other pattern Socket.io/NodeJS is following when pushes `data` into the `java.stdout.on('data', function(data) {...` call.

How can I ensure this?

UPDATE:
Okay now that I seem to have the newlines coming out with the following code:

```
  var lineBuffer = "";
  java.stdout.on('data', function(data) {  
      lineBuffer += data.toString();
      var lines = lineBuffer.split("\n");

      if (lines.length > 1) {
          var line = lines[0];
          console.log(line);
          io.emit('chat message', line);
          lineBuffer = lines[1];
      }
  });
```

But, I am seeing a new issue. The `console.log(line)` is showing different text than the `emit(line)` command:

```
listening on *:3000
0000
0
0001
1
...
```

vs. *(notice it doesn't even start at 0001)*

```
0002
2 0003
3 0004
4 0005
5 0006
6 0007
7
0008
8 0009
```

Which is coming out of the `io.emit(...)` command. So the `console.log(...)` is showing the right data but `socket.io.emit` is not!

Comment: Does this still happen with the changes I've made below?

Comment: Yes it does unfortunately. I think I will play with it more on Monday when I get back into work!

Comment: Ah I think I figured out why parts of it were coming in odd chunks. It has to do with the delay in downloading socket.io from the CDN. I included the socket.io.js code manually in the html and the rubbish in the beginning went away!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `java.stdout` is a [Readable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) in Node.js. Readable stream `'data'` events simply return chunks of data as they it come in regardless of where newline characters are.

If you want to only emit messages when there are newlines, you'll have to implement that logic yourself. Try this:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var java = spawn('java', ['-jar', 'misc.jar']);

    var lineBuffer = "";

    java.stdout.on('data', function(data) {

        lineBuffer += data.toString();

        var lines = lineBuffer.split("\n");

        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {

            var line = lines[i];

            console.log(line);
            io.emit('chat message', line);
        }

        lineBuffer = lines[lines.length - 1];
    });

    java.stdout.on('end', function() {

        console.log(lineBuffer);
        io.emit('chat message', lineBuffer);
    });
});
```

Comment: Very Cool! I'd say the one thing I would change is `lineBuffer = lines[1]` instead I could have lineBuffer = all the lines except the [0]th element. I need to look up the syntax for that though.

Comment: I seem to have a new problem now. I'll append it to my question

Comment: Good point! I've changed my code to account for cases where multiple lines are returned in one data event. I propose emitting all lines that are available at once and putting the last line onto the buffer.